# Compiling problems dealing map.find and initialization

Tags: c++, dictionary, compiler-errors

I've written a class in c++ named 'Sync'.
Then, i've created a map holding Sync objects, associated with syncID num, as follows:

```
map<int, Sync*> _syncList;
```

In one of my methods, I'm trying to search for an existing Sync object in my map, according to a given syncID number, as follows:

```
Sync* currS = *(_syncList.find(sync_id))->second;
```

I thought this would be neat, but then the compiler complained about this:

```
error: cannot convert ‘Sync’ to ‘Sync*’ in initialization
```

What can i do in order to fix this properly?

Comment: You may want to consider using [`boost::ptr_map`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_46_1/libs/ptr_container/doc/ptr_map.html).

Comment: @Space_C0wb0y - I know boost is very very helpful, but there is no need to start using another library just because you don't know how to use the standard library.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Two things:

1. Get rid of the asterisk: `Sync* currS = _syncList.find(sync_id)->second;`
2. Be sure that `find()` actually finds an element (or else you need to check the return value of `find()` for `map<...>::end`).

Comment: What is the return value of this map.find() function?

Comment: @Lilach: Find returns an `std::map<K, V>::iterator`. If this is equal to `std::map<K, V>::end()`, then the element was not found.